# RHEL 7/RAID issue

Tags: linux, raid, redhat, hp-proliant

In order to install a fresh RHEL 7, i've configured two arrays on my HPE DL360 Gen10 server, first one is a RAID 1 array with 2x 300GB HDDs, second one is a RAID 6 array with 6x 600 GB HDDs in it. Problem is on the "installation destination" screen of the RHEL installation, it shows me the two logical drives of the two arrays alright except in the second one the total capacity is completely wrong, the displayed size is 192GB when it should be around 2.4TB. Went back and checked my RAID 6 config no problems, all good.  Is this normal? Is there anything i can do?

Here's some screenshots:

https://i.ibb.co/cbhSWGs/Untitled.jpg

https://i.ibb.co/0rW9H6f/RAID-Config.jpg

Comment: Please show us exactly what you are seeing. Upload screenshots.

Comment: Hi, i've just edited the post and added the screenshots of the Raid Config and the "Insallation destination" screen

Comment: Hmm. At this point I would look through `dmesg` to see if there was some problem with detecting or adding the virtual disk.

Comment: Do you have the latest firmware installed for the RAID card? Have you tried booting a RHEL or CentOS 8 installer just to see if it recognizes the drives?

Comment: @Bert it's a brand new server i haven't really checked for firmware updates. I'll try booting RHEL and see if it recognizes the drives

Comment: Tried deleting all raid config, all drives show up ok on the RHEL installation proces. It seems like RAID 1 works ok but something wrong with RAID 6; soon as i configure it, it shows a 192 GB logical drive on the RHEL installation process..

Comment: Also updated RAID firmware to the latest version, no luck.